# Stop hot Observable from sharing value after complete

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have a hot `Observable` that I'm using `shareReplay(1)` to Multicast, but if the `Observable` is complete and its subscribed to it emits the last value.  I need it to not emit anything.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `shareReplay(1)`, you should be able to use this instead:

```js
share({
  connector: () => new ReplaySubject(1),
  resetOnError: true,
  resetOnComplete: true,
  resetOnRefCountZero: false
})
```

The `resetOnRefCountZero: false` just ensures that you can still subscribe again (and receive the shared value) even if all subscribers have unsubscribed at any point.

Note: `resetOnError` and `resetOnComplete` default to "true" in the case anyway, but I have added for clarity.

Comment: I was looking at this however in my application (Angular 9) it will not accept any arguments to `Share`  Am I missing something??

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Are you importing correctly? `import { share } from 'rxjs/operators'`

Comment: Yes,  Digging in it looks like `ShareConfig` is an addition from version 7 of rxjs and on and Angular (at least the version I'm using) doesnt support rxjs above 6.6.6 so I might have to dig in and see how `share({resetOnComplet : true})` behaves under the hood.